# TK GUI design issues and object has no attribute 'tk'?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Below is the the code that I currently have. I am beginner programmer and am writing a small program that will automate some workflow for primer design (biologist / bioinformaticists represent).

The issue I have right now is that my lack of understanding of how OOP works with TKinter. I have read numerous stackoverflow posts and watched youtube videos and read guides that try to explain it but I am still somewhat at a loss. My current understanding is that each window should be its own object, with the window above it as its parent. I've attempted to do this with my program. 
Currently I have two classes, AUTOPRIMER, and BlastAPI. AUTOPRIMER is the main window. There is a button in that window that I have created that should open up a new window when clicked. From my understanding, I have created a new object for that window called BlastAPI which deals with that particular requirement of my program. I see many guides that suggest the parent should be put in the init of the new object, but there are so many initialization variations I have seen from parent to master to args*, kwargs**. What is appropriate when? Also, currently the stack trace provides this feedback as it doesn't even compile properly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Thunderpurtz/Desktop/CGIStuff/AUTOPRIMER/autoprimercode/test1.py", line 201, in <module>
    autoprimer = AUTOPRIMER(root)
  File "/Users/Thunderpurtz/Desktop/CGIStuff/AUTOPRIMER/autoprimercode/test1.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.blast = BlastAPI(self)
  File "/Users/Thunderpurtz/Desktop/CGIStuff/AUTOPRIMER/autoprimercode/test1.py", line 150, in __init__
    eValueSetting = Entry(parent)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2673, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2289, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2259, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'AUTOPRIMER' object has no attribute 'tk'
[Finished in 0.289s]
```

Fundamentally, I think my understanding of gui programming isn't solid so if anyone can provide some insight that would be great. If this question is sort of broad, I'll be happy to clarify in the comments.

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class AUTOPRIMER:

    def __init__(self, master):
    #some functions, their content is removed as i do not believe they are relevant
        def button1():
            pass
        def button2():
            pass
        def button3():
      pass
        def getPrimers():
      pass
        def PrimerParser():
            pass
        def poolPrimers():
            pass

        self.master = master
        self.input = ""
        self.output = ""
        self.param = ""
        self.inputbool = False
        self.outputbool = False
        self.parambool = False
        self.p3filestring = '-p3_settings_file='
        self.blast = BlastAPI(self)
        master.title("Complete Genomics Inc.")

        ########## WIDGETS ##########
        entry_1 = Entry(master) #input
        entry_2 = Entry(master) #output
        entry_3 = Entry(master) #parameters

        label_1 = Label(master, text="AUTOPRIMER")
        button_1 = Button(master, text="Input Filepath: ", command=button1)
        button_2 = Button(master, text="Output Filepath: ", command=button2)
        button_3 = Button(master, text="Parameters Filepath: ", command=button3)
        button_get = Button(master, text="Get Primers", command=getPrimers)
        button_parse = Button(master, text="Parse Primers", command = PrimerParser)
        button_pool = Button(master, text="Pool Primers", command=poolPrimers)
        button_blast = Button(master, text="Blast Primers", command=self.blast)
        button_quit = Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.destroy)

        ########## LAYOUT ##########
        label_1.grid(row=0, columnspan=4) #grid doesnt take left right, it takes NSEW directions
        button_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E, padx=1, pady=1)
        button_2.grid(row=2, sticky=E, padx=1, pady=1)
        button_3.grid(row=3, sticky=E, padx=1, pady=1)
        button_get.grid(row=4)
        button_parse.grid(row=4, sticky=W, column=1)
        button_pool.grid(row=4, sticky=W, column=2)
        button_blast.grid(row=4, sticky=W, column=3)
        button_quit.grid(row=4, sticky=W, column=4)

        entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=1, pady=1)
        entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=1, pady=1)
        entry_3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=1, pady=1)

class BlastAPI:
    #class that does blast alignment on primers
    from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
    from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        super(BlastAPI, self).__init__() #saw this on another stackoverflow don't truly understand what it means

        eValueSetting = Entry(parent)
        closeButton = Button(parent, text="Close", command=self.destroy)
        inputButton = Button(parent, text="Input file", command=doNothing)
        entryField = Entry(parent)

        #layout
        self.title('Complete Genomics Inc.')

        def blastPrimers():
            filename = askopenfilename()
            with open(filename) as file:
                string = file.read()

            fasta = fasta_string

            result_handle = NCBIWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta)

            with open("my_blast.xml", "w") as out_handle:
                out_handle.write(result_handle.read())
            result_handle.close()

            result_handle = open('my_blast.xml')
            blast_record = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
            evalue = 1 #add make it a GUI alterable value blastPrimers
            item = next(blast_record)
            E_VALUE_THRESH = eValueSetting
            while True:
                with open('BlastResults.txt', w) as blast:
                    try:
                        for alignment in item.alignments:
                             for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                                 if hsp.expect < E_VALUE_THRESH: #use this to determine if the result will be applicable / HAVE USER SET / default value?
                                     blast.write("****Alignment****")
                                     blast.write("sequence:", alignment.title)
                                     blast.write("length:", alignment.length)
                                     blast.write("e value:", hsp.expect)
                                     blast.write(hsp.query[0:75] + "...")
                                     blast.write(hsp.match[0:75] + "...")
                                     blast.write(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + "...")
                        item = next(blast_record)
                    except StopIteration:
                        print("Done!")
                        break

root = Tk()
autoprimer = AUTOPRIMER(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: There are two basic approaches to using Tkinter in an OOP manner - either you derive your classes from Tkinter widgets (typically `Frame`, `Toplevel`, or `Tk` itself), or you define ordinary Python classes that merely reference widgets.  You have chosen the second approach - in which case your `AUTOPRIMER` instance is utterly unsuitable as the parent of any widget, because it's not a widget itself.  You need to pass an actual widget to `BlastAPI.__init__()`, and use that as the parent of its widgets.

Comment: `super(BlastAPI, self).__init__() #saw this on another stackoverflow don't truly understand what it means` This means to call your base class's initializer, to give it a chance to do whatever setup it needs. This is important if, e.g., you inherit from `tkinter.Frame`. But in your case, you have no base classes (except the default `object` class), so it's unnecessary. Also, the explicit `super(BlastAPI, self)` is only required for Python 2 compatibility; if you don't care about that (and your code is already not Python-2-compatible in other ways), just do `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @jasonharper So then only other widgets should be parents of widgets? What would that look like as an example?

Comment: @jasonharper also if you have resources for learning that would be great

Comment: @abarnert could you give an example of how that might look like if it was inheriting from another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there is a lot that needs work here. I imagine the missing bits are part of your main code but without them testing your code is just not possible. I work with what I could and set up your class's to inherit from the tkinter objects they needed to be. Judging by your button command in your `BlastAPI` class I am assuming this class should be a `Toplevel()` window.

I have made some changes to your code and without having `Bio.Blast` I have changed some things to what I think you might need to do.

```
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk # import tkinter as tk is good for compatibility and maintainability. Don't use *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

class AutoPrimer(tk.Tk): # Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
    def __init__(self):
        #initialization
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Complete Genomics Inc.")
        self.input = ""
        self.output = ""
        self.param = ""
        self.inputbool = False
        self.outputbool = False
        self.parambool = False
        self.p3filestring = '-p3_settings_file='


        self.entry_input = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_output = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_parameters = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_input.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="w")
        self.entry_output.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="w")
        self.entry_parameters.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="w")

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="AUTOPRIMER").grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
        tk.Button(self, text="Input Filepath: ", command=lambda: self.button1).grid(row=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="e")
        tk.Button(self, text="Output Filepath: ", command=lambda: self.button2).grid(row=2, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="e")
        tk.Button(self, text="Parameters Filepath: ", command=lambda: self.button3).grid(row=3, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="e")
        tk.Button(self, text="Get Primers",).grid(row=4)
        tk.Button(self, text="Parse Primers",).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
        tk.Button(self, text="Pool Primers",).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="w")
        tk.Button(self, text="Blast Primers", command=lambda: BlastAPI(self)).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="w")
        tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.destroy).grid(row=4, column=4, sticky="w")

        #CLASS METHODS
        #Series of buttons methods that take in the filepath and displays it in the text widget to the user

    def button1(self):
        self.entry_input.delete(0,END)
        ifp = askopenfilename()
        self.setInput(ifp)
        self.entry_input.insert(0, ifp)
        self.setInputBool(True)
    def button2(self):
        self.entry_output.delete(0,END)
        ofp = asksavefilename()
        self.setOutput(ofp)
        self.entry_output.insert(0, ofp)
        self.setOutputBool(True)
    def button3(self):
        self.entry_parameters.delete(0,END)
        pfp = askopenfilename()
        self.entry_parameters.insert(0, pfp)
        self.setParameterBool(True)

    #Methods that rely on class attributes after using above buttons to set
    def get_primers(self):
        pass
    def primer_parser(self):
        pass
    def pool_primers(self):
        pass

    #Setters and Getters
    def setInput(self, value):
        self.input = value
    def setOutput(self, value):
        self.output = value
    def setParam(self, value):
        self.param = value
    def setInputBool(self, value):
        self.inputbool = value
    def setOutputBool(self, value):
        self.outputbool = value
    def setParameterBool(self, value):
        self.parambool = value




class BlastAPI(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title('Complete Genomics Inc.')
        self.e_value_thresh = ""

        self.e_value_setting = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e_value_setting.pack() # Used pack here for quick testing. You will need to work on geometry yourself.
        tk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.destroy).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Input file").pack()
        self.entry_field = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_field.pack()


    def blast_primers(self): # Nothing is calling this function in your example.
        filename = askopenfilename()
        with open(filename) as file:
            string = file.read() # string is not being used here.

        fasta = string # No such var name in code.
        result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta) # This had a typo NCBIWW instead of NCBIWWW.

        with open("my_blast.xml", "w") as out_handle:
            out_handle.write(result_handle.read())
        result_handle.close()

        result_handle = open('my_blast.xml')
        self.blast_record = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
        evalue = 1 # Is not being used here.
        self.item = next(self.blast_record)
        self.e_value_thresh = self.e_value_setting.get()
        self.blast_write_loop()


    def blast_write_loop(self):
        # I don't really like while loops and they have problems in event based GUI's.
        # I don't think a while loop is needed here anyway.
        with open('BlastResults.txt', 'w') as blast:
            try:
                for alignment in self.item.alignments:
                    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                        if hsp.expect < self.e_value_thresh:
                            blast.write("****Alignment****")
                            blast.write("sequence:", alignment.title)
                            blast.write("length:", alignment.length)
                            blast.write("e value:", hsp.expect)
                            blast.write(hsp.query[0:75] + "...")
                            blast.write(hsp.match[0:75] + "...")
                            blast.write(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + "...")
                self.item = next(self.blast_record)
            except StopIteration:
                print("Done!")


autoprimer = AutoPrimer()
autoprimer.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for taking the time to work with me. I have some questions about your changes you made that I hope to understand. I have seen people use class(tk.Tk) in tutorials. What is the purpose of this and the difference between what I have originally done? I have a similar question with the BlastAPI(tk.Toplevel) part too. Is Toplevel part of TK?

Comment: What I have done is make my class's inherit from tkinter objects. The `tk.Tk` is inheriting from the main tkinter instance object. Its like `root = tk.Tk()` but now the class only needs to use `self` to place things on the root window. For `tk.Toplevel` this is inheriting from the `Toplevel()` widget for making new windows outside of the main window. It works much like the root window but is a 2nd movable window. Because I chose to use inherited classes I will not get the error you are receiving when it tries to create any tk widgets.

Comment: Also, the portion "command=lambda: BlastAPI(self)" I have see being used as well by other tutorials that used buttons. Why would the use of a function in the lambda form be better? In the tutorial I watched not using it lead to the function binded to the button being triggered upon the start up of the GUI and not actually pressing the button. And thanks for the Toplevel() clarification. I will need to take a closer look at the documentation.

Comment: For tkinter commands when referencing a function/method/class you have 2 options. You can save a reference to a function/method/class IE `BlastAPI`... this will activate the class when the button clicks. If you need to pass some argument to your function/method/class then you will need to use a lambda statement to prevent the creation of the button to call the function/method/class. It is just how buttons work. If you did `BlastAPI(self)` without the lambda then when the program starts it will activate the class when the button is created instead if saving a reference to it.

Comment: Would I need to do that as well for my other buttons? Right now I am getting a local variable referenced before assignment error. I'm assuming its because I defined my button function after initialized it?
I have:

self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Input Filepath: ", command=button1).grid(row=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="e")

Comment: def button1(self):
            entry_input.delete(0,END)
            ifp = askopenfilename()
            setInput(ifp)
            entry_input.insert(0, ifp)
            setInputbool(True)

Comment: the function definition line comes right after the self.button1 line in the code, just couldn't figure out how to format in the comments @Mike-SMT

Comment: You want to avoid using functions in classes. Instead use a class method. A method is essentially a function but it can be called from anywhere in the class by using the `self.` prefix. For your button1 function write it like a method like this: `def button1(self):` and then whatever code you need inside of it. Then it will not matter if the code is after the button it will work as needed. In your button you will need to change the command to `command=self.button1`.

Comment: You also need to refer to the class attributes with the `self.` prefix from within methods. This is how you can avoid using global. So you entry should be named `self.entry_input ` and your code in your button1 method should be `self.entry_input .delete(0, "end")` and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I can't quite figure out what is wrong. Now am I getting an AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'button1'. I created the method 'button1' and assigned it to command=self.button1 for the tk Button.

Comment: Its hard to troubleshoot your issue through comments. Please ask a new question or provide a link to something like github or pasteben so I can review the code.

Comment: Ok I see your problem. Your indention is bad. Fix your indention all the methods should line up right now you have them set as inside of the `__init__` method instead at the same level. See my updated answer. Sorry I missed the indention mistake in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much! I guess I missed that too. In terms of OOP would it be that because the methods aren't actually defined in the class that they can't be accessed (due to incorrect indentation)?

Comment: When the methods are indented too far they end up being a local function within the method above them and is why they no longer had a connection to the rest of the class.